# jQuery SlideToggle opens all divs with the same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Iam new here and very amateur at coding. I have a problem Ive been strugling with for a couple hours. I have 2 divs with the same ID and when I hover one, the jQuery script slides div on both of the divs. I cant explain it really good so here, i post the website where you can see the problem and the code. Thanks for help

http://prdable.tym.sk/vegas

page code

```
echo "<div id='index' style='float:left'>";
echo "SEE D-TIME<br>";
echo "<span style='font-size:18px;'><i>&quoteverything that need to be seen&quot</i></span>";

echo "<p class='roller'>Lorem Ipsum je fiktívny text, používaný pri návrhu tlačovín a typografie. 
Lorem Ipsum je štandardným výplňovým textom už od 16. storočia, keď neznámy tlačiar zobral sadzobnicu plnú tlačových znakov 
a pomiešal ich, aby tak vytvoril vzorkovú knihu. Prežil nielen päť storočí, ale aj skok do elektronickej sadzby, 
a pritom zostal v podstate nezmenený. Spopularizovaný bol v 60-tych rokoch 20.storočia, vydaním hárkov Letraset, 
ktoré obsahovali pasáže Lorem Ipsum, a neskôr aj publikačným softvérom ako Aldus PageMaker, 
ktorý obsahoval verzie Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
</div>";

echo "<div id='index' style='float:left; margin-left:40px;'>";
echo "SEE N-TIME<br>";
echo "<span style='font-size:18px;'><i>&quotmiracles you only see at n-time&quot</i></span>";

echo "<p class='roller'>Lorem Ipsum je fiktívny text, používaný pri návrhu tlačovín a typografie. 
Lorem Ipsum je štandardným výplňovým textom už od 16. storočia, keď neznámy tlačiar zobral sadzobnicu plnú tlačových znakov 
a pomiešal ich, aby tak vytvoril vzorkovú knihu. Prežil nielen päť storočí, ale aj skok do elektronickej sadzby, 
a pritom zostal v podstate nezmenený. Spopularizovaný bol v 60-tych rokoch 20.storočia, vydaním hárkov Letraset, 
ktoré obsahovali pasáže Lorem Ipsum, a neskôr aj publikačným softvérom ako Aldus PageMaker, 
ktorý obsahoval verzie Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
</div>";
```

the Jquery script

```
echo "<script>";
echo "$(document).ready(function () {
  $('div#index').hover(function () {
    $('p.roller').stop(true,false).slideToggle(300); });});";
echo "</script>";
```

Comment: I was gonna put it in other file. What do U mean? I have to write function for every single ID?

Comment: `I have 2 divs with the same ID` <-- You cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a quick example using the next method instead of closest.

http://jsbin.com/petekagu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>closest demo</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<style>
  .index {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: default;
  }
  .d-time, .e-time {
    display: none;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="index"><b>See D Time</b></div>
<div class="d-time">d time some hidden content here </div>

<div class="index"><b>See E Time</b></div>
<div class="e-time">e time some hidden content here </div>
<script>
$( "div.index" )
.hover(function() {
  $( this )
    .next()
      .stop( true, true )
      .slideToggle();
});
</script>
```

Welcome. First off, you should not name multiple elements on a page using the same ID value. Instead, use a class to name the #index div elements. In order to trigger the correct element on hover, use something like the .closest method.

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Thanks for answer. I checked out the closest() method and still now luck with it. Its applied now on the page so u can look what it does. http://prdable.tym.sk/vegas

Comment: I just updated my answer with an example using the next method. Hopefully that helps you a little more.

Comment: Thanks, I moving somewhere, i Just had to close the .index divs with .roller divs inside. But now the slided div doesnt stay open when i point at it :/ ...sorry jquery is really new to me

Comment: I think I answered your original question about not opening both divs on a single hover. If you want the divs to stay 'open' you'll have to go about it a little differently and decide how you want to close them. If you're trying to do something like a drop down menu, maybe take a look at this: http://css-tricks.com/examples/SimplejQueryDropdowns/